# Best Way to Parse JSONObjects and JSONArrays

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, arrays

So im trying to figure out the most efficient way to parse the following JSON URL'S, I will be doing this in Java on Android.

JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

private static final Context context = null;
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jarray = null;
static JSONArray jarray2 = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl2(String url) {

       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
          HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
          StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
          int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
          if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              builder.append(line);
            }
                //Recommended by Ted Hopp
                return new JSONObject(builder.toString());
          } else {
            Log.e("==>", "No Response, Check Your API KEY");
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error Response, Check your API Key", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser Activity", url + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return null;
}
```

Now the Main **ISSUE** im having is parsing the JSONObject using part 2 of my JSONParser activity.

https://api.company.com/api/systems/165756/summary?&key=e1e63de7276b04c9bb99adfd45b3a14c

Returns the following JSON

```
{
  "energy_month": 31132,
  "current_power": 1963,
  "modules": 24,
  "energy_today": 1577,
  "system_id": 165756,
  "energy_week": 215504,
  "source": "microinverters",
  "energy_lifetime": 1545467,
  "summary_date": "2013-05-03T00:00:00-07:00"
 }

   protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(final String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
             arrfortextviews=new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONObject json2 = jParser.getJSONFromUrl2(https://api.company.com/api/systems/165756/summary?&key=e1e63de7276b04c9bb99adfd45b3a14c);
                  //Added due to for some reason index return has more than 1
         for (int i = 0; i < json2.length(); i++) {
                        try {                       
                    Log.e("JSON Parser", summary + args.toString());
                    String current_power = json2.getString(TAG_CURRENT_POWER);
                    String energy_lifetime = json2.getString(TAG_ENERGY_LIFETIME);
```

However with this current code i get the following error.

```
05-03 11:31:59.765: E/JSON - Parsing of Object 2nd Time in SummaryData.java(30625): {"energy_lifetime":1545467,"energy_today":12748,"current_power":4227,"energy_month":31132,"source":"microinverters","summary_date":"2013-05-03T00:00:00-07:00","energy_week":215504,"system_id":165756,"modules":24}[Ljava.lang.String;@41dfecd0
05-03 11:31:59.765: E/JSON - Parsing of Object 2nd Time in SummaryData.java(30625): {"energy_lifetime":1545467,"energy_today":12748,"current_power":4227,"energy_month":31132,"source":"microinverters","summary_date":"2013-05-03T00:00:00-07:00","energy_week":215504,"system_id":165756,"modules":24}[Ljava.lang.String;@41dfecd0
05-03 11:31:59.780: E/JSON - Parsing of Object 2nd Time in SummaryData.java(30625): {"energy_lifetime":1545467,"energy_today":12748,"current_power":4227,"energy_month":31132,"source":"microinverters","summary_date":"2013-05-03T00:00:00-07:00","energy_week":215504,"system_id":165756,"modules":24}[Ljava.lang.String;@41dfecd0
05-03 11:31:59.780: E/JSON - Parsing of Object 2nd Time in SummaryData.java(30625): {"energy_lifetime":1545467,"energy_today":12748,"current_power":4227,"energy_month":31132,"source":"microinverters","summary_date":"2013-05-03T00:00:00-07:00","energy_week":215504,"system_id":165756,"modules":24}[Ljava.lang.String;@41dfecd0
05-03 11:31:59.785: E/JSON - Parsing of Object 2nd Time in SummaryData.java(30625): {"energy_lifetime":1545467,"energy_today":12748,"current_power":4227,"energy_month":31132,"source":"microinverters","summary_date":"2013-05-03T00:00:00-07:00","energy_week":215504,"system_id":165756,"modules":24}[Ljava.lang.String;@41dfecd0
05-03 11:31:59.785: E/JSON - Parsing of Object 2nd Time in SummaryData.java(30625): {"energy_lifetime":1545467,"energy_today":12748,"current_power":4227,"energy_month":31132,"source":"microinverters","summary_date":"2013-05-03T00:00:00-07:00","energy_week":215504,"system_id":165756,"modules":24}[Ljava.lang.String;@41dfecd0
05-03 11:31:59.790: E/JSON - Parsing of Object 2nd Time in SummaryData.java(30625): {"energy_lifetime":1545467,"energy_today":12748,"current_power":4227,"energy_month":31132,"source":"microinverters","summary_date":"2013-05-03T00:00:00-07:00","energy_week":215504,"system_id":165756,"modules":24}[Ljava.lang.String;@41dfecd0
05-03 11:31:59.790: E/JSON - Parsing of Object 2nd Time in SummaryData.java(30625): {"energy_lifetime":1545467,"energy_today":12748,"current_power":4227,"energy_month":31132,"source":"microinverters","summary_date":"2013-05-03T00:00:00-07:00","energy_week":215504,"system_id":165756,"modules":24}[Ljava.lang.String;@41dfecd0
05-03 11:31:59.790: E/JSON - Parsing of Object 2nd Time in SummaryData.java(30625): {"energy_lifetime":1545467,"energy_today":12748,"current_power":4227,"energy_month":31132,"source":"microinverters","summary_date":"2013-05-03T00:00:00-07:00","energy_week":215504,"system_id":165756,"modules":24}[Ljava.lang.String;@41dfecd0
05-03 11:31:59.895: E/SpannableStringBuilder(30625): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-03 11:31:59.895: E/SpannableStringBuilder(30625): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Comment: I would recommend against parsing JSON in the same Async task that the request was made. A layer between the AsyncTask's response and your activity can have more fine grained error handling, code reuse across requests, and logging for things like connectivity problems, server errors, JSON parsing errors etc.

Comment: @iambmelton I've updated my code - you mind taking a 2nd look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) class. It's part of the standard Android distribution. The code can be as simple as:

```
JSONObject thing = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Then you just need to navigate the object structure of `thing` to get to the data you need.

Your `getJSONFromUrl2` method could look like this:

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl2(String url) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            return new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        } else {
            Log.e("==>", "No Response, Check Your API KEY");
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error Response, Check your API Key", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        Log.e("JSON Parser", json + url + e.toString());
    }
    return null; // only gets here on an error
}
```

It's missing a bit of error handling, but since your original code is also missing it, I assume that's work you'll eventually do anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i've got a JSONParser activity im using, i've posted above. The issue im having now is im not able to Parse the JSONObject with the 2nd part of my JSONParser activity using `getJSONFromUrl2` instead of `getJSONFromUrl`

Comment: @JaisonBrooksDevelopment - You seem to have commented out the code that does the parsing. Why can't you parse the object? Have you tried simply `return new JSONObject(builder.toString());' in the `try` block?

Comment: Do you mean something like this `
  try { 
   //JSONObject jobj2 = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
   return new JSONObject(builder.toString());
   //jarray = jobj2.getJSONObject("summary");
  } catch (JSONException e) {
  }
  // return JSON String
  return jobj2;
`

Comment: @JaisonBrooksDevelopment - I mean that the `try` block should be one statement: `return new JSONObject(builder.toString());`. If it throws an exception, you can return `null`, an empty JSONObject, or exit the method with an exception. It all depends on how you want to handle errors in the calling code.

Comment: i've place some updated code above and my current logcat issues - you mind double checking to make sure i understand you fully. Thanks again Ted.

Comment: @JaisonBrooksDevelopment - While waiting for your update, I posted some sample code of my own. Your's looks okay. The exception is coming from `onPostExecute`, so it looks like your JSON parsing code is completing normally and there's another problem later.

Comment: I've fixed the issue - ill update the code above. However in my stack im getting some weird output in the log.

Comment: @JaisonBrooksDevelopment - I suggest that you mark this question as solved and start a new question regarding the log output.

Comment: @JaisonBrooksDevelopment - Are those actually errors? It looks like the output from your `Log.e()` calls. You might want to change them to be `Log.i()` so that they appear as information lines in the log instead of error lines.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, should i be concerned how many times they are repeating does this mean that section of my code is being executed this many time before it actually get the final data.

Comment: @JaisonBrooksDevelopment - I don't know where that log line is coming from. My guess is the suspicious-looking log line in the `doInBackground` loop where you are calling `Log.e("JSON Parser", summary + args.toString());` It looks like `summary` and `args` don't change, so you get the same log entry each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Volley library given by google.
It has many benefits like caching, memory management and queuing request.
You can find one best solution here :
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: Thanks for this resource. I found a solution awhile back by using GSON. But Volley sound like it really good to use. Have you had much experience with it?